# jQueryui reset widget to html

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Is it possible to remove jQueryui from elements in javascript?

IE: I make an accordion, but want a button to revert the accordion to normal html when clicked.

Comment: Surely it has a `.destroy()` API, have you consulted the documentation?

Comment: Nope - jQueryui uses mostly events and css to do what it does, but I don't think it records the changes to remove them afterwards. If it does, I can't find it.

Comment: That's not technically true, So what is [this](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#method-destroy)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just call `destroy`.  Here is the documentation: http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#method-destroy

> **destroy()**
>   Removes the accordion functionality completely. This will return the element back to its pre-init state. This method does
>   not accept any arguments. Code examples:

```
$( ".selector" ).accordion( "destroy" );
```

So in your button, you can add `onClick='$( ".selector" ).accordion( "destroy" );'`, or use an event handler that is activated on the button click.